# How to return multiple Responses from a single app route: Flask (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, heroku

I have hosted a Flask app on Heroku, written in Python. I have a function which is something like this:

```py
@app.route("/execute")
def execute():
    doSomething()
    return Response()
```

Now, the problem is that `doSomething()` takes more than 30 seconds to execute, bypassing the 30-second-timeout duration of Heroku, and it kills the app.

I could make another thread and execute `doSomething()` inside it, but the `Response` object needs to return a file that will be made available only after `doSomething()` has finished execution.

I also tried working with generators and `yield`, but couldn't get them to work either. Something like:

```py
@app.route("/execute")
def execute():
    def generate():
        yield ''
        doSomething()
        yield file
    return Response(generate())
```

but the app requires me to refresh the page in order to get the second yielded object.

What I basically need to do is return an empty `Response` object initially, start the execution of `doSomething()`, and then return another `Response` object. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually with http one request means one response, that's it.

For your issue you might want to look into:

- [Streaming Response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/), which are used for large response with many parts.
- [Sockets](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to allow multiple "responses" for a single "request".
- Making multiple queries with your client, if you have control over your client code this is most likely the easiest solution

I'd recommend reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#HTTP_flow), it gets a bit technical but it helped me understand a lot of things.

Comment: Thanks for all the resources! I think that using `Sockets` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to make is an asynchronous job. For that I recommend  you use Celery (here you have a good example: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask/page/7) or some another tool for asynchronous jobs. In the front-end you can do a simple pooling to wait for response, I recommend you to use SocketIO (https://socket.io/). It's a simple and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically an asynchronous job. You can use **Celery** or **Asyncio** for these operations. You can never ask any user to wait for more than 3 seconds - 10 seconds for any operation.

1) Make an AJAX Request

2) Initialize a socket that listens to your operation.

3) As soon as you finish the operation, the socket sends the message back, you can show the user later on through a popup.

This is the best approach you can do

*If you could share, what computation are you making then you can get more alternative approaches*

Comment: Actually, it's not exactly a computation. I am using `selenium` to login to a site, and return some data present on it. It involves many steps, and hence, takes quite a lot of time.

I think that using `Sockets` is indeed the best approach. Thanks!