# Multiple responses/checkpoints in a flask env function from python

Tags: python, flask

I have a regular python script that runs some code and returns a response with some data in a flask environment. Now, i'm looking for a way to "return" or to somehow 'pass back' some kind of message to the request sender, without interrupting the process, to report the state of progress in the code (everytime it reaches certain points or similar).

Something like this:

```
@app.route("/flask_function",methods=['GET','POST'])
def flask_function:
    -- code --
    -- code --
    some_kind_of_return_function("Checkpoint A completed")
    -- code --
    -- code --
    some_kind_of_return_function("Checkpoint B completed")
    -- code --
    -- code --
    some_kind_of_return_function("Checkpoint C completed")
    -- code --
    -- code --
    return response
```

I have no idea how to do it, or if it's even possible in flask. Any advice would be more than welcome.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61390140/4583620). What you describe is likely best implemented via sockets.

Comment: Typically there is a single returned value. To get multiple, you would make multiple requests. For example, have the task run in the background and implement endpoints which query current progress.

Comment: I'm gonna check both your approaches, thx guys!!